# curl timeout eight times

Tags: curl, ipv6, oracle-linux

Have a line of code that has always worked.

```
curl -sv http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/facter/facter-2.4.4.tar.gz | sudo tar xz; sudo ruby facter*/install.rb
```

Suddenly today, one VM on my host has started having an odd timeout problem.  I thought maybe it was some glitch in that specific VM, so I built an identical one, same OS and release, same update level, same network setup (bridged) and still got the same (new) error.  Nothing has changed on the setup, this is old code that has always worked fine.  All the other VM's on this host are working fine with the command.  Here is what happens on my Oracle Linux 6.10 VM's "suddenly": I always get eight (8) "Timeout* Trying ..." lines and then on the ninth try it works.  How might I debug how this issue has been introduced ?  Thanks.

```
[ubuntu@o610sv2 facter]$ curl -sv http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/facter/facter-2.4.4.tar.gz | sudo tar xz; sudo ruby facter*/install.rb
* About to connect() to downloads.puppetlabs.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 2600:9000:212f:c200:10:d91b:7380:93a1... Timeout
*   Trying 2600:9000:212f:4c00:10:d91b:7380:93a1... Timeout
*   Trying 2600:9000:212f:a800:10:d91b:7380:93a1... Timeout
*   Trying 2600:9000:212f:8200:10:d91b:7380:93a1... Timeout
*   Trying 2600:9000:212f:5e00:10:d91b:7380:93a1... Timeout
*   Trying 2600:9000:212f:3e00:10:d91b:7380:93a1... Timeout
*   Trying 2600:9000:212f:4800:10:d91b:7380:93a1... Timeout
*   Trying 2600:9000:212f:e00:10:d91b:7380:93a1... Timeout
*   Trying 13.226.15.26... connected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, download.puppetlabs.com has 8 IPv6 addresses of the form 2600:9000:21XX:YY00:10:d91b:7380:93a1 where the XX values match on one lookup, and the YY values are all different.

This is all cloudfront based.  If it always has been, there may be a change in your IPv6 network.  Alternatively, they may have just switched to cloudfront.  Either way, I suspect issues in your IPv6 network.

Try setting options --happy-eyeballs-timeout-ms or --ipv4 (or -4) on your curl command.

Also see if you can do an IPv6 ping of download.puppetlabs.com  You should get something like:

```
$ ping -6 -c2 downloads.puppetlabs.com
PING downloads.puppetlabs.com(2600:9000:21a2:5c00:10:d91b:7380:93a1 (2600:9000:21a2:5c00:10:d91b:7380:93a1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2600:9000:21a2:5c00:10:d91b:7380:93a1 (2600:9000:21a2:5c00:10:d91b:7380:93a1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=49.3 ms
64 bytes from 2600:9000:21a2:5c00:10:d91b:7380:93a1 (2600:9000:21a2:5c00:10:d91b:7380:93a1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=48.6 ms

--- downloads.puppetlabs.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 48.566/48.945/49.324/0.379 ms
$
```